# Insert element into array

Tags: php

I have an array

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
  array(4) {
   [0]=>
   string(1) "1"
   [1]=>
   string(2) "10"
   [2]=>
   string(3) "100"
   [3]=>
   string(3) "200"
   }
}
```

I want to insert two element into the array which must be the 3rd and last element.

Output:

```
array(6) {
 [0]=>
  array(6) {
   [0]=>
   string(1) "1"
   [1]=>
   string(2) "10"
   [2]=>
   string(1) ""
   [3]=>
   string(3) "100"
   [4]=>
   string(3) "200"
   [5]=>
   string(1) ""
   }
}
```

how can i do this?

What I have tried

```
array_splice($input,3 ,0,"");
```

Then result become like this, the array not added in the middle

```
 array(6) {
 [0]=>
  array(6) {
   [0]=>
   string(1) "1"
   [1]=>
   string(2) "10"
   [2]=>
   string(1) ""
   [3]=>
   string(3) "100"
   [4]=>
   string(3) "200"
   [5]=>
   string(1) ""
   }
 [1]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   string(1) ""
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To insert in the middle of array, you can use [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) with a length of 0.

`array_splice($input, 3, 0, "");`

To add to the array, you can use either `array_push` or `[] operator`

Comment: The `[]` operator is preferred to push because you have no function call.

Comment: On the other hand, array_push allows appending multiple elements with single call :)

Comment: Absolutely right, plus it returns the new size, so you don't have to call `count()` on it. Always depends on the use case. :)

Comment: But my output would be added as an array(1) instead of the middle of the array(0)

Comment: @user2210819 you have to operate on $input[0] in your case, as $input[0] contains the array you want to modify.

Comment: May be it is an 2d array so when i added a foreach , then its ok

Answer (score 0):

By using [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) you can insert element inside the array

```
 $array = [0 => 'Data', 1 => 'data2', 2=> 'data3'];
 array_splice($array, 1, 0, 'data append');
 var_dump($array);
```